# how to pack (no compress) file to use mulicore

Tags: zip, compression, tar

Hello Thanks in advance

There are 2000 over files and I have to archive it in DIVA so I pack the files
(I found how to archive 1000 over files in DIVA but it's impossble now)

and, There was an accident a few years a go that compressed file had flaws

so I had to pack files without compression since then

The problem is that

I normaly use .tar and when I pack files, Mac and Windows only use 1 core

so it takes too much times (1TB pack = 10 hour over)

I can select options in Bandizip when i want to make .zip - no compress, Cpu threadnumber -
but it still use 1 core. I guess no compress opiton support only 1 core

According to google search result, linux support multicore when I pack .tar

Is it really possible with no compression? and

How can I use multicore .tar or .zip with no compression in linux or Win or Mac?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pigz](https://github.com/madler/pigz) instead of gzip to compress your tar files to tar.gz. pigz can use all of your cores to speed up compression.